# MySql 5.7.17 NOW(3) not showing fractional seconds

Tags: mysql, sql

Currently on MySql 5.7.17 when I run

```
SELECT NOW(3);
```

It returns with no fractional seconds. I expect it to show like

> 2014-09-08 17:51:04.777

Instead it just returns

> 2014-09-08 17:51:04

This same issue appears when I create a new table with a column as a timestamp and give it a fsp of 3.

Any ideas what could be causing this? 
Thanks!

Comment: What are you using to query the server?  This sounds like an issue on the client side, rather than on  the server.

Comment: I think you are correct. I am using DBeaver I just tried it with a different one and it worked perfectly. This sounds like a bug on DBeavers end.

Comment: Actually the timestamp format in DBeaver is manually set. You have to go into prefs to change it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

For anyone else who has this issue:

This was because I was using DBeaver. It appears that in DBeaver you need to manually set the timestamp format in the preferences (preferences -> Result Sets -> Data Formats).

The default seems to be:

> yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss

I had to change this to

> yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss:SSS

Answer (score 0):

Just do it like this:

```
set @sam = '2014-09-08 17:51:04.777';
select LEFT(@sam,19);
```

Comment: This doesn't really solve my issue. It's that it's not returning the correct timestamps even when the fsp is set on a type.